# Direct URL access results in 404 page not found on Nginx Server

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have deployed my node.js application on nginx server and it is up and running. I am able to access the application using the domain name that i bought. For example [www.myshopping.com]  this is dummy name.
When i am navigating to other URL through the application it is working.
**For example: www.myshopping.com/cart works fine for me through navigation link on the website.**

**But when i copy this URL(www.myshopping.com/cart) and paste into browser address bar it gives me 404 page not found**

My nginx.conf file setting is as below

```
http {
       include       mime.types;
      default_type  application/octet-stream;


      server {
         listen       80;
         server_name  myshopping.com www.myshopping.com;
         root   /usr/share/nginx/build;
         index index.html index.htm;

         location / {

         }

       }
     }
```

> **How to solve this problem of direct access to a particular URL. I am a newbie in nginx world**

Comment: Try adding `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` to your `location` block.

Comment: Thank @RichardSmith  its working now.. but the fallback is not working...it does not redirect to index.html for wrong URI but gives me blank page. Kindly suggest